# How to display error if filename has invalid characters?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create and display an error message when a user tries to save a file using illegal characters. I only want the user to enter a letter from `A-Z` and `a-z`, number, and `"-" "_"`. I want to display an error if they enter characters such as: `. , /, +, =`, and so on. Simply anything that's not a letter or a number or `"-"` and `"_"`.

```
    private void saveAs(){

    FileDialog fDialog = new FileDialog(this, "Save ...", FileDialog.SAVE);
    fDialog.setVisible(true);

    String fname = fDialog.getFile();

    if(fname == null)
        return;
    fileName = fDialog.getDirectory() + fname + ".txt";

    if (fileName.matches("[-_. A-Za-z0-9]+\\.(pdf|txt|csv)")){

    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
        output.println(text.getText());
        output.close();

    } catch ( IOException e) {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(this, "Invalid Characters, Can't Save File", e.getMessage());
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `JOptionPane`? Or since you already seem to have something along those lines `MessageDialog`

Comment: underscore was some how not display after hyphen

Comment: Looks like you want an `else` clause near the bottom.

Comment: so I can write a message dialog code after the else clause that tells user that the name is invalid without using the try catch block? @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: `if (match) { // write file } else { // display message }`

Comment: Your try-catch block is actually catching an entirely different kind of error.  Basically anything that stops your program from writing to the file (such as the directory doesn't exist, or the file is not writable by the current user).

Comment: ooooh ok got it, that makes sense now. I'm still getting used to try-catch blocks, make more sense to me now. Appreciate it! Thanks ya'll!